# Streaming chart with plotly and flask

Tags: python-2.7, flask, charts, streaming, plotly

I have a flask-based webapp. I am looking to add a streaming chart to this webapp, so I need the server to send the new values for the chart every 0.3 seconds, and the browser (via javascript) to display the new chart.

I can't use bokeh, so I looked into plotly. I saw this example on how to make a [streaming chart](https://plot.ly/python/streaming_part1/), and this other one on how to [integrate plotly to flask](https://github.com/plotly/plotlyjs-flask-example/blob/master/app.py).

Can anyone help me do both? I couldn't figure out how to integrate a streaming chart to flask.